# jasperreports bar charts calculation

Tags: jasper-reports

I am trying to generate report using iReports. I have to calculate percentage of certain data the expression for which is " `new Double( $F{stock}.doubleValue() / $V{stock_SUM}.doubleValue() )` " . this is working correctly  when i put the data in columns in the detail band

but when i am using the same expression ("`new Double( $F{stock}.doubleValue() / $V{stock_SUM}.doubleValue() ) *100`"  for percentage ) for my bar graph in the summary this is not giving me correct results.

is there any property which does the same work in bar charts as  evaluation time "Auto" does for an expression.if not then how can we achieve correct percentage calculation in barcharts. i have tried changing the evaluation time  to report for the chart but that also didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

What is Your datasource? If it is SQL query I suggest prepering the needed data in it and use it in Your chars.
To calculate stock_SUM without rewriting too much, You can use [window function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Select_%28SQL%29#Window_function). :)